# On Mobile device jQuery select/unselect multilple element

Tags: html, jquery, mobile

Here is my codepen :
https://codepen.io/rushine81/pen/eYMrBoW

What I want to do is to touch drag and select(+ add/remove class) multiple elements. But I still can't figure out what is wrong with my code.
How can I remove or add class of the target element while doing touch move on mobile device?

Any help will be a great...

```
function highlightHoveredObject(x, y) {
    $(".pan-box").each(function () {
        if (!(
            x <= $(this).offset().left || x >= $(this).offset().left + $(this).outerWidth() ||
            y <= $(this).offset().top || y >= $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight()
        )) {
            $(this).toggleClass("panned");
        }
    });
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    var active = false;
    $(".pan-box").on("touchstart", function (ev) {
        active = true;
        ev.preventDefault();
        $(this).toggleClass("panned");
    });
    $(".pan-box").on("touchmove", function (ev) {
        if (active) {
            var touch = ev.originalEvent.touches[0];
            highlightHoveredObject(touch.clientX, touch.clientY);
        }
    });
    $(document).on("touchend", function (ev) {
        active = false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example. I added Mouse entries for testing on  desktop versus a mobile device. The Logic should be the same.

```js
$(function() {
  var active = false;

  function highlightHoveredObject(x, y) {
    var bounds;
    $(".pan-box").each(function(i, el) {
      bounds = {
        left: $(el).offset().left,
        right: $(el).offset().left + $(el).outerWidth(),
        top: $(el).offset().top,
        bottom: $(el).offset().top + $(el).outerHeight()
      }
      if (!((x <= bounds.left || x >= bounds.right) ||
          (y <= bounds.top || y >= bounds.bottom))) {
        $(el).addClass("panned");
      }
    });
  }

  $(".pan-box").on("mousedown touchstart", function(ev) {
    active = true;
    ev.preventDefault();
    console.log("Start");
    $(this).toggleClass("panned");
  });

  $(".pan-box").on("mousemove touchmove", function(ev) {
    if (active) {
      if (ev.originalEvent.touches != undefined) {
        var touch = ev.originalEvent.touches[0];
        highlightHoveredObject(touch.clientX, touch.clientY);
        console.log("Touch", touch.clientX, touch.clientY);
      } else {
        highlightHoveredObject(ev.clientX, ev.clientY);
        console.log("Mouse", ev.clientX, ev.clientY);
      }
    }
  });

  $(document).on("mouseup touchend", function(ev) {
    active = false;
    console.log("Stop");
  });
});
```

```css
.panned {
  background-color: #ccffcc !important;
}

#log {
  font-family: "Courier", monospaced;
  font-size: 9px;
  height: 3em;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<table border="1" width="100%" class="">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="pan-box">1</td>
      <td class="pan-box">2</td>
      <td class="pan-box">3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="pan-box">4</td>
      <td class="pan-box">5</td>
      <td class="pan-box">6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="pan-box">7</td>
      <td class="pan-box">8</td>
      <td class="pan-box">9</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div id="log"></div>
```

It can be easier to assign the boundaries into an object or variables for checking later. Also in the check, it's better to wrap the various logical statements.